# Capistrano: one task per role, multiple roles per server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a server that has two roles:

```
server "server1.example.com", :web, :worker
```

and a task that is different on each role:

```
task :start, roles: :web do
  # start the webapp...
end

task :start, roles: :worker do
  # start the worker...
end
```

In this example, I would expect both tasks to be run on server1.example.com, but it seems that only the first one is executed.

I realize that I could have combined both tasks, but it seems more future-proof this way.

Is there a way that this can work?

Comment: did you try with single quotes instead of double quotes ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
role :worker, 'my_server'
role :web, 'my_server', :primary => true
```

Its not very nice answer but try with it.